# How can I shift from one window to another window?

Tags: dialog-window

I am building a cdf application,which has multiple screens,every screen was linked to another screen.

Right now I am using `CreateDialog`. Are there any other options of displaying multiple screens to users?

Comment: The help entry of [`CreateDialog` ("See also")](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CreateDialog.html) nicely lists a number of relevant useful functions.

Answer (score 5):

Since all windows in *Mathematica* are basically `Notebook` objects (notebook windows, palettes, dialog windows, etc.), one can use the more general

```
CreateWindow[DialogNotebook[...]]
```

approach, which is a bit more customizable than `CreateDialog`. The other option is to use the more specific Dialog function, but it is rather limited when it comes to designing a mutli-windowed gui.

The other way is to abuse the floating element of e.g. `ActionMenu`:

```
ActionMenu[Graphics[Circle[], ImageSize -> 50], {
  Pane[
   "This is a window that can be used to display text when the circle 
    is clicked.", {300, 200}
  ]}, Appearance -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that this won't stay if any window is clicked, but is useful to display material temporarily.